# CS:GO case drop limit?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Hello I have been playing CS:GO all week and only gotten 1 case and 1 camo drop. I am on reduced earned xp for whatever reason if that matters. Have I reached my limit for this week or is there even a weekly limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a 1 weapon per week limit for dropped weapons.

http://www.counter-strike.net/operationbloodhound/

> How do I earn weapon drops?
>
> There is only one way to earn weapon drops. You can receive one weapon drop per week. You will receive this drop the first time you increase your Rank during the week. Your level progress bar will indicate when you are eligible for an earned weapon.

For crates, I receive 1-3 per week on average.

The 'week' resets on Tuesday nights.